# HTML table styling not setting the outside colors

Tags: html, html-table

I have this table in HTML and I'm trying to make it look prettier but no matter where I insert the "bgcolor='black'" it won't fill out the sides and make it an "enclosed" table so to speak. Here's what I'm working with:

It turns out like this:

[image: Table]

```css
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" bgcolor="black" id="tableCheckins">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="grey">
      <th style=" color:#0F0104; padding-right:60px;" value="CheckIn">Check-In</th>
      <th style=" color:#0F0104; padding-right:70px;" value="CheckOut">Check-Out</th>
      <th style=" color:#0F0104; padding-right:90px;" value="TotalHours">Working Hours</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbCheckins" bgcolor="lightgrey">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The output of your markup doesn't match the image. I suspect that's because there's more CSS loading than what you've shown. Please revise the snippet demo to show the problem accurately. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Protip: Header cell elements don't have a `value` attribute. If that's intended to be a custom property, use `data-value`.